# sed - get only text in between without spaces

Tags: regex, sed

How do I get the text in between the - in this SED statement?

Through

```
sed -n 's/.* - \\([^.]*\\).*/\\1/p'
```

File content

```
2021-08-25_@lumpsum_7000607227442711813 - App-using - ZMRUGEoLc_.mp4
```

Actual

```
ZMRUGEoLc_
```

Desired (without beginning and ending space)

```
App-using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`, you can use

```sh
sed -n 's/.* - \(.*\) - .*/\1/p' file
```

Here, `.* - \(.*\) - .*` matches any text, space+`-`+space, captures any text up to space+`-`+space and then matches the rest of the string. The whole match is replaced with the captured value and this value is printed.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/J0ln3J):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='2021-08-25_@lumpsum_7000607227442711813 - App-using - ZMRUGEoLc_.mp4'
sed -n 's/.* - \(.*\) - .*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
# => App-using
```

With `awk`, you could use

```sh
awk -F' - ' '{print $2}' file
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/W1l7V1):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='2021-08-25_@lumpsum_7000607227442711813 - App-using - ZMRUGEoLc_.mp4'
awk -F' - ' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
# => App-using
```

Here, the field separator pattern is set to space+`-`+space and Field 2 is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this `sed` to extract the match

```
sed -E 's/.[^A-Z]*(.[^ ]*).*/\1/' input_file
sed -E 's/.*- (.[^ ]*) .*/\1/' input_file
```

**Output**

```
$ sed -E 's/.[^A-Z]*(.[^ ]*).*/\1/' input_file
App-using
```

Comment: Although correct for this.  It may not always start with an alphabet.

Comment: @Lacer Indeed, that is why I included the second example.